# How do I get access to DataList's children in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to build dynamically a div element in the DataList, in item template, by javascript.
I thought about building a panel and then using panel.appendChild(div), but I have no idea how to get it.
Is it possible to do it in javascript? Is it ever right to call the controls in datalist 'children'?
If yes, I would be happy for some help.

```
  var but2 = document.getElementById("Button2");
        var dl = document.getElementById("DataList1");
        var p = dl.children[0];
        but2.onclick = function CopyDiv() {
            var iDiv = document.createElement('div');
            iDiv.style.width = "200px";
            iDiv.style.height = "200px";
            iDiv.style.position = "absolute";
            iDiv.style.top = "10px";
            iDiv.style.left = "10px";
            iDiv.style.border = '1px solid black';
            p.appendChild(iDiv);
         }
```

this is the wrong code, I guess because I didn't have any reference to the ItemTemplate.

Comment: can you please post some of your work ? what did you try till now ?

Answer (score 0):

i see one problem in your code first if `DataList` is a div and btn is a button do this :

```
<input type="button" id="Button2" onclick="CopyDiv()" val="append" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var dl = document.getElementById("DataList1");
    var p = dl.children[0];

     function CopyDiv() {
        var iDiv = document.createElement('div');
        iDiv.style.width = "200px";
        iDiv.style.height = "200px";
        iDiv.style.position = "absolute";
        iDiv.style.top = "10px";
        iDiv.style.left = "10px";
        iDiv.style.border = '1px solid black';
        p.appendChild(iDiv);
     }
  </script>
```